# Store and manage SQL Server data types

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I need to store and manipulate the following model with LINQ and store the data in SQL Server Express:

I set the property like this:

```
public DbSet<Carga> Cargas { get; set; }

public class Carga
{
    public decimal PesoLiquido { get; set; }
}
```

To manipulate values like: 1 / 1.0 / 1.10 / 1.012

What is the correct type in C# and Sql-Server?

I get errors like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Cargas.ToList());
}
```

> The 'PesoLiquido' property on 'Carga' could not be set to a 'Single' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Decimal'.

Comment: What is your model in the view. You are sending the a list of Carga not a single value.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have fixed precision data type in C# (decimal) and float precision on sql column (real or float).

Either change sql column type to money/decimal/numeric type or change C# field type to Single.

if you deal with money or cargo weight [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) would be the best - it can store all range of values without precision lost.

Default decimal on sql server is decimal(18,0). If you plan to use another scale/precision, let entity framework know: `modelBuilder.Entity<Carga>().Property(c=> c.PesoLiquido).HasPrecision(16, 10);`

Comment: Ahh, you're probably right. I thought this was about the property being set by the client, the OP is not too clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

The datatype 'Single' is the same as `float` in C#. There is no implicit conversion from `float` to `decimal`. Make sure that `decimal` values are set by the client.